# Black Screen in Xcode 6 and 6.1

Tags: ios, ios7, model-view-controller, segue

I have presented a modal view controller using segue, it works fine in iOS8 but gives the black screen in iOS 7.

Modal Presentation style is "Over Current Context".

I've cleared the background colour of the Modal View Controller so that the presenting view controller is visible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to this! I've used the following code in two projects, and it works for both iOS8 and iOS7:

```
modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:modal animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The trick is to set the modal's modalPresentationStyle to UIModalPresentation**Over**CurrentContext, and the navigationController's modalPresentation style to regular ole UIModalPresentationCurrentContext.